# when i Logging into Ubuntu OS with Domain Users It’s either System Error or Permission Denied

Tags: sssd

when i Logging into Ubuntu OS with Domain Users  It’s either System Error or Permission Denied.

I just need to do a realm permit username  and  Amend the SSSD Config file to point to AD and Restart SSSD Services then the issue can resolved .
this is Intermittent issue so i not able to know the root cause and fix it permanently ?

can any one please help on this ?